# Can't access properties of my network adapter

Tags: windows-7, networking

I need to change my default IP and DNS settings on my LAN adapter. Currently, when I go into the network settings, I get this:

[image]

No matter what I do, I can't get into the properties to change the settings. I've not touched these settings in literal years, so I don't know how long this has been a problem.

I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium. I can't recall doing anything that would affect this, but I'm not sure. I'm the only user on the machine (its my home desktop), so I know I'm the administrator account, here's proof from the User Accounts section of the control panel:

[image]

Is there a way I can fix this so I can make the changes I need to make?

Comment: Just because you are the only user, does not mean, you are an Administrator.  So provide us a screenshot, that shows, that you are indeed in the Administrator user group.

Comment: @Ramhound Edited, added in the image from the Control Panel. :)

Comment: Try diabling it and renabling the card to see if this fixes the issue.  Right click your network icon on the bottom and open view network connections and click on your adapter settings and click disable then wait and hit enable see if it brings it back had this issue a few weeks ago on one of the enterprise systems at work.

Comment: You must be admin in order to access Local Area Connection Properties so this is not the problem. First try to open CMD as admin, and type `sfc /scannow`. If this doesn't help, try downloading an anti malware. Please give a feedback if it worked.

Comment: Can you try **[this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/tcpipv4-properties-button-disabled/347899fa-b60a-40a3-ad2c-78ef5e0dca37?auth=1)** ?

Comment: Try to turn off the user account control settings and restart your computer

Comment: @Divin3 I did both the SFC scan and scanned for antivirus and malware, and nothing changed.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin That didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you do anything before to get this locked?  Malware or anything is there a reason you are trying to mess with the properties?

Comment: @NetworkKingPin Trying to change my DNS settings back to automatic instead of a static setting. I have no idea if I have done anything. Virus and malware scans come back clear, and I'd not have touched these settings in literal years.

Comment: Try this is you have not already you need "Local Area Connection to be your connection name. You can find this when you Open the Network sharing center. Then go to change adapter settings. you enter the following command via CMD.exe   `netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" dhcp`

Comment: Create a backup of `c:\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys`, try replacing it with another one taken from another PC with the same Windows version. Reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

1. Reset TCP/IP -> netsh int ip reset `<log>` (log is needed, ex.
   `C:\ResetIP.txt`) don't reboot
2. uninstall-“Client for Microsoft Networks”- reboot
3. Reinstall “Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)” -> Add protocol, click on “Have
   disk…” and browse to `C:\%WinDir%\inf\nettcpip.inf` *

   %WinDir% is Windows folder
4. Reinstall -> “Client for Microsoft Networks”
   add a Client afterwards, it will show in the list

Comment: I'm not able to uninstall the client - I click the button, but nothing happens.

Comment: Try to update the drivers from device manager.